# How to satisfy nested generic requirement of Class<T> in kotlin

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I am trying to call a method where it's signature includes a parameter of `Class<T>`

below is the sample code in kotlin

```
val response: ResponseEntity<ResponseObject<*>> = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/users", user, ResponseObject::class.java)
```

what i am trying to achieve is to get rid of the `<*>` in responseObject and let it be

```
val response: ResponseEntity<ResponseObject<User>> = ???
```

but i am not sure on what is the correct syntax to provide to satisfy the `Class<T>` requirement

i tried

```
ResponseObject<User::class.java>::class.java
```

but that is not a valid syntax. any pointers?

The real problem is if i use `*` i don't know how exactly to infer the `User` instance from there correctly.

Comment: This usage seems correct for me if your response object is type of User : "ResponseEntity<ResponseObject<User>>"

Comment: btw you don't have to specify type at all `val response = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/users", user, ResponseObject::class.java)`

Comment: What is the signature of the `testRestTemplate.postForEntity` method?

Answer (score 0):

ok I managed to solve my problem using type casting using `when`

```
@Test
    fun testCreateUser() {
        val user = User(id = null)
        val response = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/users", user, ResponseObject::class.java)
        val responseObject = response.body
        when (val returnedUser = responseObject.model) {
            is User -> {
                assertNotNull(returnedUser.id)
                assertEquals(UserStatus.active, returnedUser.status)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the signature of the method then you may try something similar to the following:

```
class ResponseEntity<T : Any>(val body: T)

class ResponseObject<T : Any>(val model: T)

data class User(val id: Long, val status: String)

fun <M : Any, K : ResponseObject<M>> postForEntity(paht: String, model: M): ResponseEntity<K> {
    return TODO()
}

val response: ResponseEntity<ResponseObject<User>> = postForEntity("/users", User(1, "good"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val response = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/users", user, ResponseObject::class.java as Class<ResponseObject<User>>)
```

Or a helper function if you need it more than once for different parameters

```
inline fun <reified T> classOf<T>() = T::class.java

val response = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/users", user, classOf<ResponseObject<User>>())
```

(in both cases the type `ResponseEntity<ResponseObject<User>>` should be inferred)

Comment: thanks, but i am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to model.User`

Comment: Then this depends on the library you use, sorry.